# Regex for capturing a block of variable assignments

Tags: c++, regex, string

I have tokens that I need to parse and would like to have a regex that captures them. Here is how the tokens look

```
EVAL
INPUT A = 5; 
INPUT B = 6; 
...
INPUT LongVariableName = 10;
```

I want to validate that every `EVAL` block is formatted correctly for parsing. A naive approach I have is to take these tokens and build a string out of them like so:

`"EVAL:INPUT A = 5;#...#INPUT EXAMPLE = 10;#"` where we signify that we have an `EVAL` with a `:` separating it from the inputs. Each input is then delimited by a `#`.

Or getting into the spirit of regex, `EVAL:(INPUT ID = NUM;#)+`,

- where `ID` begins with an alphabetic character but can contain any amount of alphanumeric characters after,  and
- `NUM` is any nonnegative integer.
- there must always be at least one INPUT.

I want this regex to make sure that within the string that we build, each input is instantiated (with `INPUT`), named (with `ID`), assigned a value and terminated with  `= NUM;`, and delimited correctly (with `#`).

I am however having trouble how to design the regex so that we are able to capture variable names of any length greater than one.

Comment: What do you mean by *every* "EVAL" block? Your example shows just one. If there can be more than one per file, how are they delimited? Is it just a new "EVAL" after the last "INPUT..." for the previous "EVAL"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes, there can be multiple , but all the lexing, parsing, and string building is all done by me. but you are correct-- if there are two EVAL blocks, the second EVAL will come after the last INPUT in the previous EVAL.

Comment: I suggest you modify your example to included two blocks in the file, with no "..." lines and remove "END_OF_FILE" if that is not actually in the file. Then state that that is the content of the file. By doing so readers can use your example to test code.

Comment: I don't see the point to bother with a regex based validator, just use your own parser to validate. However each assignment line would match something like `^\s*INPUT\s+(\w+)\s*\=\s*(\d+)\s*;\s*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validation you can match the string to the following regular expression to determine which blocks are formatted correctly:

```
^EVAL *\r?\n(?:INPUT +[a-z][a-z\d]* += +\d+; *\r?\n)+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y6hmeh/1)

For formatting replacing matches of the following regular expression with a space will get you close:

```
\r?\n(?!EVAL\b)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M3dG4J/1)

If the string looks like this:

```
EVAL
INPUT A = 5; 
INPUT B = 6; 
INPUT LongVariableName = 10; 
EVAL
INPUT Dog = 55; 
INPUT Cat9Lives = 6;
```

the following string will be result:

```
EVAL INPUT A = 5;  INPUT B = 6;  INPUT LongVariableName = 10; 
EVAL INPUT Dog = 55;  INPUT Cat9Lives = 6;
```

Comment: I will provide further explanation after 1 sleep cycle, which is about to commence.

Comment: thank you! any ideas why it wont capture the last line on this one? https://regex101.com/r/63KSXv/1

Comment: I assumed from your examples that an integer was required, so a float violates the formatting. To permit (non-negative) integers or floats change the regular expression to `^EVAL *\r?\n(?:INPUT +[a-z][a-z\d]* += +\d+(?:\.\d+)?; *\r?\n)+`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NI4a1A/1)

Answer (score 0):

> **I am however having trouble how to design the regex so that we are able to capture variable names of any length greater than one**

I suggest that you construct a state machine for this.
You could define states in which your lexer is currently in and based on that process the strings.

You could use a loop and inside you construct several `if` statements to detect the state of the lexer and have the corresponding action in it.

So initially your lexer's state would be set to read `#` followed by a string `INPUT` then after reading it the lexer's state would be set to read `ID`. For this you could use sub-states (say `readID`), i.e initially the lexer's `readID` state would be set to a constant `READ_FIRST_CHAR`(that you define as a macro or enum) which would be any of the alphabetic character, right after reading the first character of `ID` you set the `readID` state to read `READ_INTERIOR_CHAR`, which is any alphanumeric character.

I hope you get the idea. The language you defined is very simple and I don't think you would need a parser for it.